# Angular project and server files on localhost

Tags: python, angular

`ng serve` command runs a server instance on a `localhost`. I would like to use some server-side scripts on the same `localhost` and communicate between angular app and the `http` server.

I have some issue by not knowing in which directory I should place Python scripts. So that I can run extend the functionality of Angular app, to gather data from localhost server?

EDIT:

I am visiting `http://localhost:4200/data.php` in a browser, but I am always getting a 304 redirect. I figure this could be due to incorrect placing of php files. I've put it in `src`, `..src` and `app` folder, but nothing seem to work.

Comment: Please post what "some  issue " you are getting

Comment: I am not able to run server script. For example, i've put some simple server pyhton and php script in src folder, and visited  localhost:4200/data.php and also localhost:4200/data.py , but  default home screen of Angular app is getting served instead of php/py script. How do I get this "angular server" to serve server scripts?

Comment: you cannot, you need another web server in different port.

Answer (score 0):

`Root` directory if it is one or two files - like `configs` etc. 
If you actually need a server side app maybe it's better to make that the root project and have angular in a `view` folder.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I've put it in src folder, since that is probably root in a fresh project. To test if everything works I've visited http://localhost:4200/data.py and also http://localhost:4200/data.php, but angualr just serves the home page of angular app.

Comment: okey, yes it won't work like this. angular bundles the .ts,.html.css files and  serves them `/dist` folder where u can access it in the address you mentioned. what do you want to achieve exactly ? if you want have a server side app, create some REST endpoints or start a websocket server, add that at the root and then put angular in a `root_directory/view` folder. In that way you can start your server in another port and angular will run at port `4200`. Check this https://medium.com/@ervib/deploy-angular-4-app-with-express-to-heroku-6113146915ca Then you can easily communicate those two apps